# Budgets for Territory in Salesforce

Tags: territory-management, territory

We are testing out Territory Management for our organization. One of the requirements is to assign monthly & yearly budgets for the territories. 
I looked at using a Territory Budget Custom object which in essence should have a year, month & budget amount field. 
In Territory, I need fields to summarize current month's & current year's budget based on the information that I enter in Territory Budgets custom object. 
I hit a limitation here because custom objects cannot be associated to Territory in Salesforce.

As of now, I could think of 2 workarounds:

1. Use Standard Territory Managment, also create custom Territory
   object which stores Territory Name & Territory Id. Use this custom
   territory object to summarize budget information in Standard
   Territory.
2. Do not use Territory Management at all - Create custom
       objects for managing Territory and Territory Budgets.

Has anyone come across this scenario? Please let me know how you achieved your solution/workaround.

Thanks!!